# Do I have to use controller for simple "Who am I" page in cakephp?

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I have a page with some links:

- Home
- Who Am I
- Contacts

I made the link code:

```
<li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Contacts',array('controller' => 'contacts','action' => 'contacts')) ?>/li>
```

Do I have to create "ContactsController.php" just to show a simple html page with a small paragraph of text or there is an easier way (without any controller perhaps)?

Thank you!

Comment: In your ContactsController, change the action to `index` if it's just a simple view or something. If you want to edit contacts, make an `edit` action. It's much more convenient and easier to understand for other programmers who are editing your code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CakePHP comes with the `Pages` controller for things like this. You can create the view for the page here:

`app/View/Pages/my_page.ctp`

Then you can access it here:

`http://example.com/pages/my_page`

If you don't want the `pages/` part to be in the URL, just add a line to your `app/Config/routes.php` file, like this:

`Router::connect('/my_page', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'my_page'));`

Comment: Ok, but page is a controller. I was looking for a way to to without it. I'll edit to make it clear in the question.

Comment: Forget my comment. Now I understood. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, otherwise why would you use an MVC framework? :)

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense. Now I see that for small projects cakephp might not be the better framework.

Comment: Well it's really dependent on your application. It's not _that_ much more code, and I find that MVC helps to organize your code logically. I'd give it a shot and see if you like it, otherwise drop off CakePHP and move to a more simplistic framework (if you even need one).